# Querying multiple values through parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfquery

so my application loads in a user's contacts and stores their phone numbers but I want to query these phone numbers against ones stored in Parse to determine whether any of their contacts are using the application.

So, I know how to work through every phone number as a single query by using something like the code below inside a for loop,

```
                NSString *phoneNumber = CFBridgingRelease(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, i));
               //parse query for any matches to the phone number
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
[query whereKey:@"phoneNumber" equalTo:phonenumberfieldfriend.text];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // The find succeeded.
        NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d users.", objects.count);
        // Do something with the found objects
        if (objects.count == 0) {
            //uialert letting the user know that no phone number matches the query
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No User"
                                                            message:@"No user matches this phone number"
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            phonenumberfieldfriend.text = @"";







        }
        //if there is only one number matching the query
        if (objects.count ==1) {
            for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                NSLog(@"%@", objects);
                usernamefriend =[ object objectForKey:@"username"];
                numberfriend = [object objectForKey:@"phoneNumber"];
                firstnamefriend = [object objectForKey:@"firstName"];
                lastnamefriend  = [object objectForKey:@"lastName"];
                emailfriend = [object objectForKey:@"email"];

                add.hidden=true;
                phonenumberfieldfriend.hidden=true;
                confirmuser.hidden=false;
                NSLog(@"one user entered %@",usernamefriend);



            }
        }
        //if there is more than one phonenumber matching the query as
        //the user to input the friends username
        //instead
        if (objects.count>1) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"More than one user!"
                                                            message:@"More than one user with this number please enter a username instead!"
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
             phonenumberfriend.text=@"Please enter a username";
            add.hidden=true;
            adduser.hidden=false;

        }

    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];}
```

but I would like to know whether it is possible to search all the contacts phone numbers with a  single query?

Comment: So your saying instead of doing for (PFObject *object in objects) you just want to find all of them at once with `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`?

Comment: Yes I want to search every phone number from the person's contacts and find their matching user in the class _user

Comment: So your issue isn't the query its retrieving the phone numbers from the device contacts app and checking if there is one in the User class?

Comment: No, I know how to retrieve the numbers from the contacts app, but I want to check through all the phone numbers from the contact app with a single query instead of doing an individual query for each number.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this numerous ways, provided I understand what your vision is:

One way is simply preform the query and simply do :

`query getFirstObjectInBackground:`

https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/getFirstObjectInBackground

this narrows it down to only one phone number that matches your query parameters.

or `getObjectInBackground:`

So in other words just delete findObjects and replace with getFirstObjectInBackground and the first result that matches will be returned